# Weird Text Boxes Showing in Gedit and Bluefish Editor, as well as Firefox

Tags: firefox, gedit, text, bluefish

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Installed on my computer, I use **Gedit** and **Bluefish** for html and css edits(If theres any better ones out there let me know :) ) And for some reason apostrophes and quotes sometimes show these weird text boxes, and I can do a Find & Replace to fix some of them, but most of them I miss when I'm viewing a webpage.

When the Code is being rendered it shows a Question Mark.

[image]

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/yKpt84v.png)

Comment: That looks like a wrong encoding (the numbers are unicodes). From memory: 0093 is a " 0092 is a '  0085 is ... :) Can you check from command line with `file {filename} what the encoding is? Are those windows files perhaps and -not- UTF8?

Comment: and s+r is not needed; there is a (perl) command called "piconv" that can do thise from command line ;)

Comment: The html file was created in Windows in Dreamweaver. I'm also a noob when it comes to the terminal lol so I'm unable to find the file

Answer (score -1):

Try searching and replacing these characters in the source code:

```
‘ and ’ replace with '
“ and ” replace with "
```